# Batch script run from address bar in \\wsl$ not working as expected

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, batch, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been using a handful of simple batch scripts to open my editor (Neovim) in whatever folder I was in in the explorer. I added the directory of the batch scripts to my PATH and now I run them from the address bar. Here is an example of `nvim-wsl.bat`:

```
pushd %*
wt new-tab --title NeoVim-wsl -d . -p Ubuntu-20.04 bash -i -c nvim
popd
```

So, when run from the address bar, it opens a new windows terminal tab in the current directory using the wsl profile, and then runs the bash command `nvim`.

This has worked wonderfully in the past for all sorts of other little scripts also. This works great in explorer.exe when I'm on the windows file system, but when I try it from the address bar of explorer.exe while exploring `\\wsl$`, it does not work, and instead opens up Neovim at `/mnt/c/Windows` i.e. `C:\Windows`.

When I run the inner command `wt new-tab --title NeoVim-wsl -d . -p Ubuntu-20.04 bash -i -c nvim`  from the command line inside `\\wsl$` it works as expected, however.

I should also add it doesn't appear to be a UNC path incompatibility...entirely. When `\\wsl$` is mapped to a network drive and I run the above script, I get a Neovim instance at `/home/MyUsername`...

What exactly is going on, and how might I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found one way to make it work, although I'm not sure it's "right":

1. Mount your `\\wsl$` "share" as a networked drive in Windows, we'll call it `U:`
2. Mount this new drive in wsl as `/mnt/u`
3. Commands from the address bar in `explorer.exe` in `U:` are now aware of the correct path and are working as intended.

The reason I don't think this is "right", is because, even though we're working in the wsl file system, because it's a mounted windows drive in wsl, I think all the file operations are being passed through the server that transforms the operations between file systems...twice. I haven't done a lot of testing, but I am noticing some slow downs. I'll probably just continue to work with the wsl file system in the terminal. Hopefully someone else can provide some clarity!